# Relevant category for questions about the hardware

Tags: discussion, support, acceptable-question, asking-questions, specific-question

I'm newbie and I have a question regarding the hardware. The question is indirectly linked to security, but most of it relates hardware: about routers, wi-fi, wi-fi boosters, etc.

Can you please tell me what category/directory is the most appropriate for these questions?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's relate electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: can you give examples of the types of question you want to ask. As @AviD commented, there are a lot of different areas.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the specifics, but there is a [hardware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag. But note that not all of what you mentioned would fit there - e.g. routers is typically not about the hardware (but I dunno, you might have a very specific question about that...)